# Azure Functions: Querying endpoint throws error 500.37 - ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-function-app

I deployed some changes to `Azure Functions`, but it looks like my endpoint is not reachable. For a while, I kept getting "Function host is not running" errors. Lately, the errors became "HTTP Error 500.37 - ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit". How do I resolve this issue? I restarted my function app, but it didn't resolve anything.

**EDIT:** I looked at my activity log. I see a lot of errors like this:

> ```
> Operation name 
> SlotSwap 
> Time stamp 
> Fri Aug 14 2020 13:36:40 GMT-0500
> (Central Daylight Time) 
> Event initiated by 
> SlotSwapJobProcessor
> ```
>
> "Failed swapping site. Error: Cannot swap slots for site '...'
> because the warmup requests to application in '...' slot have timed
> out. Please check the application logs to determine what causes the
> timeouts."

and this:

> ```
> Operation name
> List Web Apps Functions Host Keys
> Time stamp
> Fri Aug 14 2020 17:27:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
> Event initiated by
> [email]
> Error code
> BadRequest
> Message
> Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.
> ```

Everything was working up until today and I haven't made any changes to cause this issue.

Comment: Because the problem you encountered is now running normally, you can rule out your code or release and other factors.

Comment: It is recommended that you [raise a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to confirm your problem on the portal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today. (I found this question by searching for *List Web Apps Functions Host Keys*). Restarting the function app seemed to solve the issue, but only for a few minutes. Then the function app would still produce the impossible to debug *Function host is not running* error. I was also seeing an `OutOfMemoryException` error message under the *Overview* in the Azure portal.

After some digging I realised that I had configured `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `beta` (under Settings → Configuration in the Azure portal). I changed it to `~3` as suggested in the [Azure Functions runtime versions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#changing-version-of-apps-in-azure). After changing the function app runtime version, it started to work again.

Comment: Thanks. My extension version was 3. I think that this issue is generic and could be thrown for many reasons. Unfortunately, I deleted the function app and created one from scratch. I'm not sure how I'd have dealt with this if it had occurred in production.

Comment: Also, I've had many issues with slots so far. For now, I've stopped using slots.